# Combining the results from multiple iterations of the same SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, iteration

I have a table that contains effective dated transaction records for each employee. I want to create a results set that reflects the same selected attribute values for each employee as of the end of each year from 2018 thru 2022. The base SQL looks like this:

```
/*
END OF PERIOD DATES
2021 - 01/02/2022
2020 - 01/03/2021
2019 - 12/29/2019
2018 - 12/30/2018
*/

DECLARE @PeriodYear int  = 2020;
DECLARE @PeriodEnd  date = '01/03/2021';

SELECT   
/* Change End of Period Date Here ********************************* */
    @PeriodYear   AS 'Period', 
/* Change End of Period Date Here ********************************* */
    @PeriodEnd    AS 'Period End Date', 
    A.EMPLID      AS 'ID', 
    B.NAME        AS 'Name', 
    A.EMPL_STATUS AS 'Status',
    A.DEPTID      AS 'Dept'
/* Change End of Period Date Here ****************************************************** */
   YEAR(@PeriodEnd) - YEAR(B.BIRTHDATE) - 
    CASE 
      WHEN MONTH(@PeriodEnd) * 100 + DAY(@PeriodEnd) 
        >= MONTH(B.BIRTHDATE) * 100 + DAY(B.BIRTHDATE) THEN 0
      ELSE 1
     END AS 'Age at Period End'
FROM EMPL_TRANS A, PERSONAL_DATA B
WHERE 
/* Change End of Period Date Here ************************************* */
           A.LAST_HIRE_DT <=   @PeriodEnd
/* Change End of Period Date Here ************************************* */
     AND ( A.TERMINATION_DT >  @PeriodEnd
           OR A.TERMINATION_DT IS NULL)
     AND A.EFFDT =
        (SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM EMPL_TRANS A_ED 
        WHERE A.EMPLID   = A_ED.EMPLID
/* Change End of Period Date Here ******************************************** */
          AND A_ED.EFFDT <=  @PeriodEnd )
     AND A.EMPLID   = B.EMPLID
     ;
```

Here are the input tables:

```
[EMPL_TRANS table][1]

| EMPLID | EFFDT    | EMPL_STATUS | ACTION | DEPTID | LAST_HIRE_DT | TERMINATION_DT |
|--------|----------|-------------|--------|--------|--------------|----------------|
| 244848 | 11/11/20 | Inactive    | TERM   | HO1164 | 2/2/17       | 11/11/20       |
| 244848 | 3/3/18   | Active      | XFER   | HO1164 | 2/2/17       |                |
| 244848 | 2/2/17   | Active      | HIRE   | I1120  | 2/2/17       |                |
| 291302 | 4/3/02   | Active      | HIRE   | I1124  | 4/3/02       |                |
| 251258 | 4/2/21   | Inactive    | TERM   | S1214  | 5/3/01       | 4/2/21         |
| 251258 | 5/2/20   | Active      | XFER   | S1214  | 5/3/01       |                |
| 251258 | 5/3/01   | Active      | HIRE   | DU1245 | 5/3/01       |                |
| 283485 | 3/3/19   | Inactive    | TERM   | DU1318 | 7/1/12       | 3/3/19         |
| 283485 | 7/1/12   | Active      | HIRE   | DU1318 | 7/1/12       |                |
| 302912 | 8/5/05   | Inactive    | TERM   | DU1317 | 6/1/03       | 8/5/05         |
| 302912 | 6/1/03   | Active      | HIRE   | DU1317 | 6/1/03       |                |


[PERSONAL_DATA table][1]

| EMPLID | Name                     | Birthdate |
|--------|--------------------------|-----------|
| 244848 | Larone,Adam              | 1/1/80    |
| 291302 | Ireson,Jonathan P        | 1/2/80    |
| 251258 | Benjelloun,Mohammed Simo | 1/3/80    |
| 302912 | Larocque,Joseph D        | 1/4/80    |
| 283485 | Schier,Matthew           | 1/5/80    |
```

This is the result set I'm looking for

```
[Result set table][1]

| Period | Period End Date | "ID"   | Name                     | Status   | Dept   | Age at Period End |
|--------|-----------------|--------|--------------------------|----------|--------|-------------------|
| 2018   | 12/30/18        | 244848 | Larone,Adam              | Active   | I1120  | 34                |
| 2018   | 12/30/18        | 251258 | Benjelloun,Mohammed Simo | Active   | DU1245 | 38                |
| 2018   | 12/30/18        | 283485 | Schier,Matthew           | Active   | DU1318 | 31                |
| 2018   | 12/30/18        | 291302 | Ireson,Jonathan P        | Active   | I1124  | 40                |
| 2018   | 12/30/18        | 302912 | Larocque,Joseph D        | Inactive | DU1317 | 50                |
| 2019   | 12/29/19        | 244848 | Larone,Adam              | Active   | HO1164 | 35                |
| 2019   | 12/29/19        | 251258 | Benjelloun,Mohammed Simo | Active   | DU1245 | 39                |
| 2019   | 12/29/19        | 283485 | Schier,Matthew           | Inactive | DU1318 | 32                |
| 2019   | 12/29/19        | 291302 | Ireson,Jonathan P        | Active   | I1124  | 41                |
| 2019   | 12/29/19        | 302912 | Larocque,Joseph D        | Inactive | DU1317 | 51                |
| 2020   | 1/3/21          | 244848 | Larone,Adam              | Inactive | HO1164 | 36                |
| 2020   | 1/3/21          | 251258 | Benjelloun,Mohammed Simo | Active   | S1214  | 40                |
| 2020   | 1/3/21          | 283485 | Schier,Matthew           | Inactive | DU1318 | 33                |
| 2020   | 1/3/21          | 291302 | Ireson,Jonathan P        | Active   | I1124  | 42                |
| 2020   | 1/3/21          | 302912 | Larocque,Joseph D        | Inactive | DU1317 | 52                |
| 2021   | 1/2/22          | 244848 | Larone,Adam              | Inactive | HO1164 | 37                |
| 2021   | 1/2/22          | 251258 | Benjelloun,Mohammed Simo | Inactive | S1214  | 41                |
| 2021   | 1/2/22          | 283485 | Schier,Matthew           | Inactive | DU1318 | 34                |
| 2021   | 1/2/22          | 291302 | Ireson,Jonathan P        | Active   | I1124  | 43                |
| 2021   | 1/2/22          | 302912 | Larocque,Joseph D        | Inactive | DU1317 | 53                |
```

I want to execute the SQL for each of the date combinations (i.e. change the two parameters for each run) but have all the results sets combined into one result set. Is that possible?

Comment: Where do these period end dates come from?

Comment: Meanwhile using string literals as aliases has been deprecated a long time. And aliases like a, b are just awful to work with. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3 And those long outdated joins really should be modernized, it's only been 30 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: I guess you could create a temp table and insert the results of your query into that temp table for each set of parameters. Then finally select the rows from the temp table.

Comment: Frankly [Period] and [Period End Date] both logic not clear.Also see for [Period] 2020 ,[Period End Date] is 2021 dates.Please explain the logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join all transactions for each period, use `ROW_NUMBER()` function to tag transactions and get the last for the period and then filter for tag = 1 to keep only the latst

I have added a `PERIODS` table to ease the whole process

```
;with
[PERIODS] AS (
    select *
    from (values 
    (2018, CAST('2018-12-30' AS DATE)),
    (2019, CAST('2019-12-29' AS DATE)),
    (2020, CAST('2021-01-03' AS DATE)),
    (2021, CAST('2022-01-03' AS DATE))
    ) [PERIODS] (PeriodYear, PeriodEnd)
),
RES AS (
    SELECT 
        p.PeriodYear, p.PeriodEnd, pd.EMPLID, pd.Name, tr.EMPL_STATUS, tr.DEPTID,
        DATEDIFF(YEAR, pd.Birthdate, tr.EFFDT) age
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.PERIODYEAR, TR.EMPLID ORDER BY TR.EFFDT DESC) N
    FROM PERSONAL_DATA PD 
    JOIN EMPL_TRANS TR ON PD.EMPLID = TR.EMPLID
    JOIN PERIODS P ON tr.EFFDT < p.PeriodEnd
)
SELECT *
FROM RES
WHERE N=1
ORDER BY 1,3
```